# How can I launch .cmd files on a remote machine?

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell, cmd, remote-access

I need to be able to launch a .cmd file that is on a remote machine, *from within the directory that the file resides on that machine*.

I've tried: `invoke-command -ComputerName test123 -ScriptBlock { cmd /c c:/myfile.cmd }` in powershell, which launches the .cmd, but then fails because it can't find the corresponding .cmds that this one launches (which all reside in the same directory).

Is there a way to launch this .cmd file, and have it's execution persist? i.e., even after the powershell window is closed, the .cmd will continue to run on the remote machine.

Comment: You are specifing c:\myfile.cmd (with wrong type of slash - maybe powershell cares). Try wmic process call create c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe, c:\users

Comment: @tonybd what is the syntax for what you provided? Specifically, what is the purpose of `c:\users`?

Comment: I would like to know the answer as well. Because I keep having to use schtasks for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx As far as I know that is the only way to get it to persist

Comment: c:\users is the default directory you want for the program you are starting. Use Help wmic process call create /?. So a fuller command - wmic /node:"@%userprofile%\desktop\ComputerName.txt" /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\NicSpeed.html" /failfast:on process call create %systemroot%\system32\cmd /k dir, %userprofile%. ComputerName.txt contains a list of computer names (without \\\\) or IP addresses (or both - you can mix).

Comment: wmic /node:"@%userprofile%\desktop\ComputerName.txt" /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\NicSpeed.html" /failfast:on process call create "%systemroot%\system32\cmd /k dir", C:\users

Comment: @tonybd PowerShell can handle forward slashes as well as backslashes for path separators.

Comment: This seems like a lot more than I need. I just want to execute a specific .cmd file on a single machine.

Comment: You only use what you want of it. wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "cmd c:\autoexec.bat", c:\users. Specifies directory and keeps running.

Comment: Hm, when I put that in a cmd line and execute I get:  `C:\>wmic /node:test123 process call create "cmd c:\path\to\remote.cmd", c:\remote\workingdir` Invalid Global Switch.

Comment: Are there spaces in your paths? And I'm going to work now.

Comment: Because pasting your command does not give me invalid switch, putting paths that exist it works.

Comment: Because pasting your command does not give me invalid switch, putting paths that exist it works. Wmic is finnicky, post actual command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the working directory in the scriptblock. Add a `Set-Location` before calling the batch script:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName test123 -ScriptBlock {
  Set-Location 'C:\'
  & cmd /c ".\myfile.cmd"
}
```

---

If you need to create a detached process, you can do that for instance via WMI:

```
$hostname = 'test123'
$command  = 'C:\path\to\script.cmd'
$workdir  = 'C:\working\directory'

$p = [wmiclass]"\\$hostname\root\cimv2:Win32_Process"
$p.Create($command, $workdir)
```

Note that you need admin privileges on the remote host for this.

Comment: Hm, with this I get `Ampersand not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; use "&" to pass ampersand as a string.` Any idea what to do?

Comment: @MrDuk `&` is PowerShell's call operator, so you shouldn't be getting this message. Please show how you're running the code.

Comment: @Cole9350 For asynchronous execution he'll have to resort to a scheduled task or launching the process via WMI. There are more elegant ways to the latter than `wmic`, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers based on your above comment, I assume that once I close the PowerShell window, the .cmd I'm trying to launch will terminate?

Comment: @MrDuk Yes, just like if you where sitting at remote machine and running the .cmd locally and closed the window.

Comment: When I try to put your wmi code into a .bat file and run it, I get errors like `'$hostname' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @MrDuk The code is PowerShell, so you can't just put it into a batch file. Write it to a PowerShell script instead (.ps1).

Comment: Hm, getting closer :)  `test.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system`

Comment: @MrDuk Either run `Set-ExecutionPolicy = RemoteSigned` in a PowerShell prompt once, or run your script from a command prompt like this: `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\path\to\your.ps1"`

Comment: @Ansgar, thats what I was afraid of. I usually use a scheduled task that launches 1 minute from now and removes itself once it is done executing, definitely not elegant tho.