# How to create a detached background process in PowerShell. Need to create it inside an AzureDevOps pipeline task

Tags: android, powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to setup a azureDevOps pipeline for android testing on self-hosted agent(windows). For this, I need to start an emulator as a detached process in background.

I am successfully able to start a process in background using following command.

Start-Job -Name EM -ScriptBlock {D:\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator -avd testAVD -no-audio -no-window }

But this process is attached to the parent process, and hence, when Azure pipeline exits the current task, as a part of clean up - it kills this emulator also (beats my purpose of creating the emulator in first place).

So, Can anyone suggest how can I start a detached background process in powerShell? Thanks in advance!

P.S: There is one relevant post, however, it looks to be very java specific.
[Start a detached background process in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023458/start-a-detached-background-process-in-powershell)

I have tried

1. Start-Job -Name EM -ScriptBlock {& D:\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator -avd testAVD -no-audio -no-window }
   This looks to be not working.
2. StartThread-Job -Name EM -ScriptBlock {D:\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator -avd testAVD -no-audio -no-window }
   For this, Azurepipeline task doesnt even exit. So, this also doesnt work. Moreover, I dont think this would be a solution either, beacause by definiation of StartThread-Job, it starts a new thread in same process. Dont think it talks about detachment at all.

Any suggestions?.

Comment: this doesnt really make sense. pipeline runs while the script inside runs. even if you would succeed in creating a detached process that runs your stuff - pipeline will exit as soon as you finish creating it, because your main script exits. what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hey das. You are correct - only when the said task is the last task of pipeline, Not otherwise. In my case, said task is one of the first tasks I m doing. Problem I m trying to solve-- I am trying to create an emulator, on which I will run some connectedandroidtest later in next task (cannot club these tasks as this one is a gradle task). I am doing this all as a part of testing the new app I am developing.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers