# How to open VSCode from command prompt as its own thread without hijacking the terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

On Windows, when I open a folder from the terminal in VSCode with the "code ." command, it opens VSCode correctly but the terminal window becomes a slave, running all console commands from the app without returning command to me. If I close the terminal, VSCode also closes, it seems that the application thread is being run as child of the terminal process that gets killed with its parent. The same does not happen with "xp . ", my shortcut for the file explorer.

My question is how to make VSCode open as its own process letting the terminal be free.

Comment: Which OS? Linux, macOS, WSL, Windows?

Comment: Looking at their other questions, I see a windows screenshot. If so, maybe uplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023458/start-a-detached-background-process-in-powershell

Comment: Windows, edited.

Comment: Not a duplicate since it's not PowerShell but windows terminal

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

cmd /c start "VSCode" "code.exe" .